# Filter out url from string

Tags: c++, regex, string, url

Im trying to filter out urls from a string that contains lots of special characters, blank space and urls. I have tried to use regex but it fails, it manages sometimes to line up the url but  the output still contains special characters and blank space, so here I am. Best regards P

```
string str;
std::ifstream in("c:/Users/Petrus/Documents/History", std::ios::binary);
std::stringstream buffer;

if (!in.is_open()){
    cout << "Failed to open" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "Opened OK" << endl;
}

buffer << in.rdbuf();

std::string contents(buffer.str());

std::ofstream out("urls.txt");

unsigned counter = 0;
std::regex word_regex(
    R"(^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(//([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?)",
    std::regex::extended
    );
auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(contents.begin(), contents.end(), word_regex);
auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
    std::smatch match = *i;
    std::string match_str = match.str();
    for (const auto& res : match) {
        counter++;
        std::cout << counter++ << ": " << res << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "  " << match_str << '\n';
}

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: You might be able to get away with a simpler `regex` depending on the data file contents.

Comment: A regex is almost certainly the way to go here, but we won't be able to help you debug the regex unless you can give examples of inputs that it didn't work on.

Comment: Here´s the beginning of the file im trying filter from. The url links are way down in the file.  http://pastebin.com/wA9N1Gbi

Answer (score 1):

a few steps to simplify (and debug) the regex:

1. use named groups `(?<groupname>regex)` to help identify what's what and access results.
2. for 'grouping only' `()`'s, use `(?:regex)` to "not remember" captures, also helps clarify what's going on

once done, just a few tweaks "fixes" this regex for all your inputs:

```
(?<protocol>https?:\/\/)(?:(?<urlroot>[^\/?#\n\s]+))?(?<urlResource>[^?#\n\s]+)?(?<queryString>\?(?:[^#\n\s]*))?(?:#(?<fragment>[^\n\s]))?
```

- I changed the negated char classes to not match newlines or spaces: `[^#\n\s]`
- specified that any segment after urlRoot is optional.
- added the string "https?" to limit results to valid urls

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH1eS9/3) output:

[image]

and the match groups (truncated but all there):

[image]

Comment: Could you provide me a code example of using ` ^\s*(?<protocol>(?:[^:\/?#\n]+):)?(?:\/\/(?<urlroot>[^\/?#\n]*))?(?<urlResource>[^?#\n]*)(?<queryString>\?(?:[^#\n]*))?(?:#(?<fragment>.*))?$` 

Did you look at pastebin.com/wA9N1Gbi to see what im working with? Best regards

Comment: Petrus, I updated my demo with your exact input. see https://regex101.com/r/bH1eS9/3

Comment: Oh I see! Well Im having difficulties to use the regex expression that u provided. I have tried to replace mine with your but doesnt work unfortune. Any ideas?

Comment: hard to say without a working code sample. you could go to http://ideone.com/ and create a working example using a string instead of a file? (disclaimer: i'm a regex guy, not a c++ guy!)

Comment: Aiight! The regex expression that you provided me from that site dosent seem to be the right for c++. Do you have any clue of where I should try to find the right expression that might work mate.

Comment: i believe the regex is sound and c++ should support all constructs here, it could be a string escape issue? do you need doubled backslashes perhaps? (see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2064649&seqNum=2) also: try wrapping whole thing in () as in your original

Comment: can we chat somewhere else if possible? Best regards

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112195/discussion-between-sweaver2112-and-petrus-lindblom).